# Adding user info into a Wordpress e-mail

Tags: wordpress, sendmail, contact-form

I have a custom-post-type.
If a user can fulfill this "need" they click a button that opens a modal.
Within the modal is the submit button, which will email the admin of the site, telling him that a user can fulfill that specific need.

I want to load the admin email, user email, need-title, and that specific site-name (this is WPMU).

I have done this in the modal box, but how do I get the modal box information into an email?

I have coded the modal as such:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Fulfill this Need!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="http://gogibb.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/GoGibbChild/sendmail.php" method="post">
        Thank you 
        <strong><?php global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();
                echo $current_user->user_login . "\n";
          ?></strong>
         for doing your part and helping others.<br/>
         You are offering to fullfill a need:<br/><br/>
        (<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>) from
        <?php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'agency',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => '1')); // how many posts to show

  // Put into the loop
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
   $the_query->the_post();
   echo '<td><a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></td></tr>';

  endwhile;



  // Restore original Post Data if needed
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>.<br/><br/>

        Please add a little bit about yourself and why you'd like to fulfill the need. We'll get back to you very shortly.<br/>

        <textarea class="fulfill-textarea"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Fulfill</button><br/><br/>
```

My php mail script is as follows. The top part I know doesn't work properly but I wrote it out in a way to show you the information I need from wordpress. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php


$adminemail = $_POST['adminemail'];
$currentusername = $_POST['currentusername'];
$useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
$currentneedtitle = $_POST['needtitle'];
$sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
$commentz = $_POST['commentz'];

$to = "$useremail";
$subject = "[$sitename] Someone wants to fulfill your need!";
$body = "$currentusername has fulfilled your need!<br><br>

$currentneedtitle on $sitename <br/><br/>

$commentz <br/><br/>

Email the user at $useremail today to get the process started.
";

$headers = "From: $adminemail" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $to" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
header("location: http://www.waxbayouhuntingclub.com/wax/thank");
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by hiding all the dynamic data in input fields and passing them the same way I do above (I changed some of the var names). Here's the code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="useremail" name="useremail" value="<?php global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();
                echo $current_user->user_email . "\n";
          ?>">

       <input type="hidden" id="adminemail" name="adminemail" value="<?php echo bloginfo('admin_email');?>">



       <input type="hidden" id="needtitle" name="needtitle" value="<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>">
       <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="<?php global $current_user;
                get_currentuserinfo();
                echo $current_user->user_login . "\n";
          ?>">
       <input type="hidden" id="sitename" name="sitename" value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>">
```